# vue js online payment integration

Tags: vue.js, payment-gateway

In vuejs, I have integrated online payment gateway it's working as expected after complete the transaction it should redirect to my page. I given the return url to the bank and they redirected to my page, but I got the error message like Cannot POST /. Please let me know how should I give the return url?

currently I given the return url as `http://localhost:8081/#/checkoutsuccess`

`checkoutsuccess` is the vue page to load after the transaction.

Comment: while checking the bank redirection using fiddler, I got the 404 response and the query param value.

Comment: This doesn't include enough information to answer. Who was POSTing to whom? You -> payment gateway? User -> you? User -> payment gateway? What gateway are you using? Can you show us any code?

Comment: Now I'm using SBI payment gateway. After completion of bank transaction the Bank return to my site, what URL given in RU(Return URL). below the vuejs code to call the bankpayment gateway and encdta.  `code
callpayment() {
        this.$http
          .get(this.$serviceToGetSBIEncDetails + this.transId)
          .then(res => {
            this.encData = res.bodyText;
            window.location =
              "https://uatmerchant.onlinesbi.com/merchant/merchantprelogin.htm?encdata=" +
              this.encData +
              "&merchant_code=TEST_SERVICE";
          });`

Comment: `String strEnc = "&ITC=|Amount=1|Ref_no="
     + prn+ "|Account_Misc=0|Account_EMD=0"
     + "|Account_TAX=0|Account_TFA=0|Account_SURCHARGE=0|Dept_id="+ payeeId
     + "|Amount_EMD=0|Amount_TC=0|Amount_RF=0|payment_mode=INB"
     + "|RU=http://localhost:8081/#/checkoutsuccess" + "";`

Comment: How would any external website reach your `localhost:8081`?

Comment: @IvanStarostin is there any other way to redirect to localhost?

Comment: Currently I'm working in dev mode, so that the page is not redirected to my localhost after taking the build and deploy in to tomcat server the page is redirected to our local host. Now I need to capture the parameters from the return url, I tried this way `this.$route.query.encdata` but I'm getting null value. Can any one help me to read this param value?